# $\mu^n_{s} \xrightarrow[n \uparrow \infty]{w} \mu_{s}$ implies $\mu^n_{t_k} \xrightarrow[n \uparrow \infty]{w} \mu_{t_k}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\{\mu^n_{s}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}},\mu_s$ denote a measures with mass bounded by $1$ and that for almost every $s$ in $[0,T]$, $\mu^n_{s} \xrightarrow[n \uparrow \infty]{w} \mu_{s}$ (weak convergence of measures).

I want to show that for each $t<T$, we have a sequence $\{t_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $t_k \downarrow t$ such that $\mu^n_{t_k} \xrightarrow[n \uparrow \infty]{w} \mu_{t_k}$  for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm not absolutely sure if this property is true, but it seems true. If I could prove it, it would make a proof that I'm trying to do a lot easier and that's why I'm asking if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{ s \in [0,T] : \mu^n_{s} \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{w} \mu_{s}\}$.
Suppose that the "almost every" you mentioned is based on the Lesbeque measure $\lambda$, so what you have is that $\lambda(S)=T$, and what you want to prove is that for every $0\le t < T$ and every $\epsilon>0$ such that $t+\epsilon<T$, $$(t,t+\epsilon)\cap S \ne 0$$
which is always true because
$$\lambda( (t,t+\epsilon)\cap S)=\lambda ((t,t+\epsilon)\cap [0,T]) = \epsilon>0$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited a typo in your solution. Just let me add that the last line is true because there is a set $D$ with measure zero such that $[0,T]=S \cup D$. This implies that $\lambda(C \cap [0,T])=\lambda(C \cap (S \cup D))=\lambda((C \cap S) \cup (C \cap D))=\lambda(C \cap S) + \lambda(C \cap D) = \lambda(C \cap S)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I also approved your edit. Thank you for it